# Tinkerpop Gremlin: Batching of multiple select query into one batch select query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

In Tinkerpop Gremlin,
I have two select query

1. `g.V().has("id","foo").out().values("x").toList();`
2. `g.V().has("bar","foo").out().values("id").toList();`

Now Can we club these query into one batched tinkerpop gremlin?
I tried 
`g.V().has("id","foo").out().values("x").union(__.V().has("bar","foo").out().values("id")).toList()`

but this leads to a single list instead of two separate list. I want to extract the response of these two queries separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start your traversal with some dummy value and then `union()` the two traversals together:

```
gremlin> g.inject(0).union(V(1).out().fold(),V(2).in().fold())
==>[v[3],v[2],v[4]]
==>[v[1]]
```

Comment: Without `inject`: `g.V(1).out().fold().union(identity(), V(2).in().fold())`